# reunion of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
Create table tbl_test(
    col1 nvarchar(255),
    col2 nvarchar(255),
    sum1 int,
    sum2 int,
    sum3 int)

Create table tbl_test2(
    col1 nvarchar(255),
    col2 nvarchar(255),
    sum1 int,
    sum2 int,
    sum3 int)

Insert into tbl_test (col1, col2, sum1, sum2, sum3)
    select 'a','a',  1 , 1 ,1
        union all
    select 'a','b', 2,2,2
        union all
    select 'a','c', 3,3,3   

Insert into tbl_test2 (col1, col2, sum1, sum2, sum3)
    select 'a','a',  1 , 1 ,1
        union all
    select 'a','b', 2,2,2
        union all
    select 'b','a', 3,3,3
```

/*
What I would like my procedure to do is obtain a new table tbl_result:

```
tbl_result:
    col1 | col2 | sum1 | sum2 | sum3
     'a'    'a'     2      2     2      || 1 + 1 
     'a'    'b'     4      4     4
     'a'    'c'     3      3     3
     'b'    'a'     3      3     3
```

*/
--So I would like to have some kind of reunion between the 2 tables.

--The method I found so far is :

--  Step 1: find the common values

```
Update a 
    set a.sum1 = a.sum1 + b.sum1,
        a.sum2 = a.sum2 + b.sum2,
        a.sum3 = a.sum3 + b.sum3 
from tbl_test a join tbl_test2 b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2
```

--  Step 2: find the new values

```
Insert into  tbl_test (col1, col2 ,sum1,sum2,sum3)
    select 
            b.col1,
            b.col2,
            b.sum1,
            b.sum2,
            b.sum3
    from tbl_test a right join tbl_test2 b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2
        where a.col1 is null and a.col2 is null

 select * from tbl_test
```

Unfortunately this is not good enough. If my tables have 1.000.000 records a join is probably not an optimal solution. Any ideas?

Comment: If your tables have the proper indices, even 100 millions **rows** (database tables have **rows** - not records) are **NOT** a problem!

Comment: @marc_s: Can you comment on my answer, please? Will the `COALESCE()` on millions of rows be slow, should it be rewritten as UNION of 3 JOINS (`INNER` + `LEFT-IS NULL` + `RIGHT-IS NULL` )?

Comment: @ypercube: I've heard very different opinions about `COALESCE` and quite honestly never had a chance to test it myself on a large enough set of data - so I can't really say. But the compound index on both tables is **definitely** a must!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `FULL JOIN` and a compound index in both tables on `(col1, col2)`:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.col1, b.col1)                   AS col1
        COALESCE(a.col2, b.col2)                   AS col2
        COALESCE(a.sum1, 0) + COALESCE(b.sum1, 0)  AS sum1
        COALESCE(a.sum2, 0) + COALESCE(b.sum2, 0)  AS sum2
        COALESCE(a.sum3, 0) + COALESCE(b.sum3, 0)  AS sum3
FROM
    tbl_test a
  FULL JOIN
    tbl_test2 b
      ON  a.col1 = b.col1
      AND a.col2 = b.col2
```